# Efficient linear algebra for block-diagonal matrices in compressed format

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have a linear system in which all the matrices are block diagonal. They have `N` blocks identical in shape.

Matrices are stored in compressed format as numpy arrays with shape `(N, n, m)`, while the shape of the vectors is `(N, m)`.

I currently implemented the matrix-vector product as

```
import numpy as np

def mvdot(m, v):
    return (m * np.expand_dims(v, -2)).sum(-1)
```

Thanks to broadcasting rules, if all the blocks of a matrix are the same I have to store it only once in an array with shape `(1, n, m)`: the product with a vector `(N, m)` still gives the correct `(N, n)` vector.

My questions are:

- how to implement an efficient matrix-matrix product that yields the matrix with shape `(N, n, m)` from two matrices with shapes `(N, n, p)` and `(N, p, m)`?
- is there a way to perform these operations with a `numpy` built-in (possibly faster) function? Functions like `np.linalg.inv` make me think that `numpy` was designed to support this compressed format for block diagonal matrices.

Comment: Sounds like you can also use standard matrix multiplication with sparse representation for a block diagonal system.

Comment: What do you mean? using the `dot` method?

Comment: Yes, instead of working with a tensor (N,n,m) as a compressed format you can keep them as 2d matrices (N*n,N*m) with sparse representation and use sparse matrix matrix multiplication or matrix vector multiplication.

Comment: Which spare matrix class do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two arrays of shape `(N,n,p)` and `(N,p,m)`, respectively, and their product should be of shape `(N,n,m)` where element `[i,:,:]` is the matrix product of `M1[i,:,:]` and `M2[i,:,:]`. This can be achieved using [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
import numpy as np
N = 7
n,p,m = 3,4,5
M1 = np.random.rand(N,n,p)
M2 = np.random.rand(N,p,m)
Mprod = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',M1,M2)

# check if all the submatrices are what we expect
all([np.allclose(np.dot(M1[k,...],M2[k,...]),Mprod[k,...]) for k in range(N)])
# True
```

Numpy's `einsum` is an incredibly versatile construction for complicated linear operations, and it's usually pretty efficient with two operands. The idea is to rewrite your operation in an indexed way: what you need is to multiply `M1[i,j,k]` with `M2[i,k,l]` for each `i,j,l`, and sum over `k`. This is exactly what the above call to `einsum` does: it collapses the index `k`, and performs the necessary products and assignments along the remaining dimensions in the given order.

The matrix-vector product can be done similarly:

```
M = np.random.rand(N,n,m)
v = np.random.rand(N,m)
Mvprod = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',M,v)
```

It's *possible* that `numpy.dot` can be coerced with the proper transposes and dimension tricks to directly do what you want, but I couldn't make that work.

Both of the above operations can be done in the same function call by allowing an implicit number of dimensions within `einsum`:

```
def mvdot(M1,M2):
    return np.einsum('ijk,ik...->ij...',M1,M2)

Mprod = mvdot(M1,M2)
Mvprod = mvdot(M,v)
```

In case the input argument `M2` is a block matrix, there will be a leading dimension appended to the result, creating a block matrix. In case `M2` is a "block vector", the result will be a block vector.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.5 and above, the previous example can be simplified using the matrix multiplication operator `@` ([numpy.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)) which treats this case as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
N = 7
n,p,m = 3,4,5
M1 = np.random.rand(N,n,p)
M2 = np.random.rand(N,p,m)
Mprod = M1 @ M2  # similar to np.matmul(M1, M2)

all([np.allclose(np.dot(M1[k,...],M2[k,...]),Mprod[k,...]) for k in range(N)])
#True
```